# cannot catch org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter exception in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I am have my Spring MVC (3.1.1.RELEASE) application who uses Hibernate (3.6.9.Final).
Its configured with Log4j.

```
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener=OFF
```

When I try to add a row into my table, if the length of the field exceeds the maximum size, in the logs I can see this exception :

```
hibernateTemplate.merge(ba);
```

In the logs :

```
2012-07-06 15:22:35,546 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - <ERROR: value `too long for type character varying(70)>`
```

But on the other hand, in my code, all I can catch is this **DataAccessException** exception:

```
Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into T_MYTABLE (BA_NUMBER, USR_ID, BA_ID) values (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update"}
```

This is not the exception I want.

Do you know how I can get the message from the log file, within my application ?

I have tried catching **HibernateException** but without success.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the exception.getCause() on the DataAccessException?

Comment: I just tried using getCause() but I just get this : "Could not execute JDBC batch updateCould not execute JDBC batch update"}"

Comment: Hi guigui42,Did you manage to catch exception logged by JDBCExceptionReporter. It logs exception thrown by hibernate while committing batch uupdates. I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way :

```
 catch(DataAccessException e)
    {
            Throwable t = e.getCause();               
            SQLException ex = (SQLException) t.getCause();
            while(ex != null){
                 while(t != null) {
                     t = t.getCause();
                 }
                 logger.warn("SQLException="+ex.getLocalizedMessage());

                 ex = ex.getNextException();
            }
    }
```

source : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=987395&view=previous

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Here's what I ended up with after sifting through all the various wrappers  and useless generic errors.
Seems like there should be a better way. I get the feeling that this is brittle and implementation specific.

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResponse handleDataAccessException(DataAccessException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String errorString = null;
    Throwable t = e.getCause();      
    if(t instanceof PersistenceException) {
        t = t.getCause();
        if(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            t = t.getCause();
            if(t instanceof BatchUpdateException) {             
                SQLException sqlException = null;
                sqlException =  ((SQLException) t).getNextException();
                if(sqlException instanceof PSQLException) {
                    errorString = ((PSQLException)sqlException).getServerErrorMessage().toString();
                    log.error("Caught exception: type=\"" + sqlException.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + errorString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    Set<ResultCode> resultCodes = new HashSet<ResultCode>();
    resultCodes.add(ResultCode.SERVER_ERROR);
    errorResponse.setResultCodes(resultCodes);
    return errorResponse;
}
```